# Could previous account be deleted?

Tags: support, help-center, accounts

I have two accounts. When I attended stackoverflow for real I had forgotten all about the another account. I would really like to get my first account deleted, it is https://stackoverflow.com/users/768092/david-a-d-konrad - I dont even remember / know the credentials. Is that possible, with a little help from the moderators?

Comment: You were given an answer to this here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254078/how-do-you-request-deletion-of-your-account . Why delete that and ask again?

Comment: Yes, sorry - Because I cannot login on the old account. Dont know the credentials.

Comment: @BradLarson: So, it is impossible to have an old inactive account deleted? I'll try the helpcenter.

Comment: @davidkonrad: How should the mods know it's yours? Give them some way to verify it, and you can use the standard way to merge them. Maybe even the standard way to delete it (after recovery), if they don't remember this question ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator. yes, I know the dilemma. Have gone through the helpcenter, waiting for their response. They should be able to tell me what email I used for the first account, and by that I may figure out what my password was.  There are very few people in the world having the name I have, so I hope they consider that also.

Comment: @davidkonrad: I´m sure they won´t tell you any mail addres just like that. And if your name is David Konrad (like of your account), it isn´t exactly unusual.